# How to send a request to whois.nic.online by socket?

Tags: perl, sockets, whois

I made a script that uses a socket to get an info from a whois server. All is ok, but when i pass any of .online tld's domain response from whois.nic.online is:

> DOMAIN NOT FOUND!

But, when i use command `whois -h whois.nic.online example.online` in the terminal (Linux), i get all info that i needed.  What is the problem with the WHOIS.NIC.ONLINE?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket;

if (scalar @ARGV == 0 or $ARGV[0] =~ /^[\d]{1, 20}/) {

  print "There is no parameter\n";
  exit();

}

my $domain_name = $ARGV[0];
my $query_resp_server_socket = new IO::Socket::INET(
  PeerAddr => 'whois.iana.org',
  PeerPort => 43,
  Proto => 'tcp');

print {$query_resp_server_socket} "$domain_name\n";
print $query_resp_server_socket "\r\n";
my @answer_from_iana = <$query_resp_server_socket>;
close($query_resp_server_socket);

my $responsive_whois_server;

foreach (@answer_from_iana) {

  if(/whois\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2, 20}\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2, 20}$/) {
    if ($& eq "whois.nic.online") {
      $responsive_whois_server = "whois.nic.online";
    }
    else {
      $responsive_whois_server = $&;
    }
  }

}

my $query_data_socket = new IO::Socket::INET(
  PeerAddr => $responsive_whois_server,
  PeerPort => 43,
  Proto => 'tcp');

print {$query_data_socket} "$domain_name\n";
print $query_data_socket "\r\n";

my @answer_from_resp_server = <$query_data_socket>;
close($query_data_socket);

if ( scalar @ARGV == 1 ) {

  print @answer_from_resp_server;

}
elsif( scalar @ARGV == 2 and $ARGV[1] eq "-exp" ) {

  foreach (@answer_from_resp_server) {

    if (/paid-till|Registry Expiry Date/) {

      print $_;

    }
    else {

      print "Info was not found."

    }

  }

}
elsif( scalar @ARGV == 2 and $ARGV[1] eq "-stat" ) {

  foreach (@answer_from_resp_server) {

    if (/state|Domain Status/) {

      print $_;

    }
    else {

      print "Info was not found."

    }

  }

}
elsif ( scalar @ARGV == 2 and $ARGV[1] eq "-adm" ) {

  foreach (@answer_from_resp_server) {

    if (/person|Registrant Organization/) {

      print $_;

    }
    else {

      print "Info was not found."

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Try this: `print {$query_data_socket} "$domain_name\r\n";`

Comment: There are some other aspects of the script that need some work, but I believe that's the key issue.

Comment: @Erwin To use print() wouldn't you need to enable flush? Other wise the data sits in a buffer. It would make more sense to use the send function from IO::Socket.

Comment: My main point was to change `\n` to `\r\n`. The buffer will be flushed. Did you actually test it? There’s certainly a fair number of things I’d do different as well, if I were asked to write this code, but I thought that was beside the point. 

Comment: @Erwin, would you recommend turn all of this stuff into OOP?

Comment: @user508828 - It could be a useful (practice) exercise. Aside from that I see little benefit from doing that for _this_ script. My thoughts were more along the lines of proper option parsing `use getopt` and (as @FractalLotus suggested) using appropriate `IO::Socket` methods, putting common code in a function, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way for me to do this. Instead of iterating over an array of whois servers, I get them from `whois.iana.org`. My new solution is:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Socket qw/ :DEFAULT :crlf /;
use Getopt::Long;

use constant {
    IANA_HOST  => 'whois.iana.org',
    WHOIS_PORT => '43',
};

my $host   = '';
my $domain = '';

GetOptions(
    'host|h=s'   => \$host,
    'domain|d=s' => \$domain,
);

die "Usage: whois.pl [--host -h] [--domain -d]" unless $domain;

socket(my $sock_fd, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die "Socket: $!";

unless( $host ) {
    connect($sock_fd, pack_sockaddr_in(WHOIS_PORT, inet_aton(IANA_HOST))) or die "Connection: $!";

    send($sock_fd, "$domain$CRLF", 0);

    my $data = join('', <$sock_fd>);

    my ($whois_server) = $data =~ m/whois:\s{8}(.+)/i;

    close($sock_fd);

    unless ( $whois_server ) {
        die "Unknown/Unsupported TLD\n";
    }

    socket($sock_fd, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    connect($sock_fd, pack_sockaddr_in(WHOIS_PORT, inet_aton($whois_server))) or die "Connect to $whois_server failed: $!";

    send($sock_fd, "$domain$CRLF", 0);

    $data = join('', <$sock_fd>);

    print "$data";

    close($sock_fd);
    exit(0);
}

connect($sock_fd, pack_sockaddr_in(WHOIS_PORT, inet_aton($host))) or die "Connect to --host=$host failed: $!";

send($sock_fd, "$domain$CRLF", 0);

my $data = join('', <$sock_fd>);

print "$data\n";

close($sock_fd);
exit(0);
```

Perhaps it is not the best solution, but it is better than the one I asked for help with.
It is not the last version of the solution. Some logic could be moved to subroutines.